# Load can only be called when the EntityCollection or EntityReference does not contain objects

Tags: entity-framework

As Title showed, When I use lazyload of Entity Framework 4.1 which turned tracking off I got the error.

Complete exception message:

> When an object is returned with a NoTracking merge option, Load can only be called when the EntityCollection or EntityReference does not contain objects

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Can you post code where exactly this was raised?

Answer (score 3):

Set the `Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled` field of your `DbContext` to `false`:

```
using (var dbContext = MyDbContext())
{
    dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    return dbContext.MyProducts.AsNoTracking().Where(product => product.DepartmentId = departmentId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem.  Apparently it is a bug in EF 4.1
[Bug ticket](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/679399/entity-framework-4-1-using-lazyloading-with-notracking-option-causes-invalidoperationexception)

Comment: Right Now I have to add a related property to make sure the enitty will be proxied