# c# Entity framework stackoverflow exception crashing w3wp

Tags: c#, iis-7, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-4

entity framework is failing on IIS and crashing the W3wp process.
I am getting a stack-overflow exception logged in the event log along with a memory dump file.

The following exception message is from that memory dump file.
It looks like this error is occuring on GetDataForDateRange endpoint. When I run this endpoint with a larger date range i recevid a out of memory exception. This method is using lazy loading to load entities. And does not use NoTracking()
Is there an releationship with memory out of exception and stackoverflow?

```
0000003bae9a5fe0 00007ffd2e2bae60 *** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for EntityFramework.dll
System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PropertyPushdownHelper.VisitSetOp(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.SetOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
0000003bae9a60d0 00007ffd2e0cd927 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
0000003bae9a6160 00007ffd2e2bafbd System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PropertyPushdownHelper.VisitSetOp(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.SetOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
0000003bae9a6250 00007ffd2e0cd927 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
0000003bae9a62e0 00007ffd2e2bafbd System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PropertyPushdownHelper.VisitSetOp(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.SetOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
0000003bae9a63d0 00007ffd2e0cd927 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
0000003bae9a6460 00007ffd2e2bafbd System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PropertyPushdownHelper.VisitSetOp(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.SetOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)

--- I omitted at least 1500 lines of same message. 

0000003baea1bee0 00007ffd2e2bafbd System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PropertyPushdownHelper.VisitSetOp(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.SetOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
0000003baea1bfd0 00007ffd2e0cd927 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
0000003baea1c060 00007ffd2e0bf2e0 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PropertyPushdownHelper.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.PhysicalProjectOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
0000003baea1c100 00007ffd2e0cd927 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
0000003baea1c190 00007ffd2e0cd927 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
0000003baea1c220 00007ffd2e0ce298 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PropertyPushdownHelper.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.VarDefOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
0000003baea1c280 00007ffd2e0cd927 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
0000003baea1c310 00007ffd2e0cd927 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
0000003baea1c3a0 00007ffd2e0bf2e0 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PropertyPushdownHelper.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.PhysicalProjectOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
0000003baea1c440 00007ffd2e0bf443 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.NominalTypeEliminator.Process(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.StructuredTypeInfo, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmFunction,System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmProperty[]>)
0000003baea1c4d0 00007ffd2de3da6d System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.ProviderCommandInfo> ByRef, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMap ByRef, Int32 ByRef, System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Set`1<System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntitySet> ByRef)
0000003baea1c570 00007ffd2de3ca89 System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory, System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbCommandTree, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterceptionContext, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.IDbDependencyResolver, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.ResultAssembly.BridgeDataReaderFactory, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory)
0000003baea1c6e0 00007ffd2de3c488 System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderManifest, System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbCommandTree, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterceptionContext)
0000003baea1c750 00007ffd2de3b9bc System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.CreateCommandDefinition(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext, System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbQueryCommandTree)
0000003baea1c7d0 00007ffd2de360a4 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext, System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbQueryCommandTree, System.Type, System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.MergeOption, Boolean, System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Span, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.Tuple`2<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter,System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression>>, System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.AliasGenerator)
0000003baea1c900 00007ffd2dc54874 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(System.Nullable`1<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.MergeOption>)
0000003baea1ca30 00007ffd2dc54b67 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1+c__DisplayClass7[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].b__6()
0000003baea1ca90 00007ffd2dc54d00 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.Func`1<System.__Canon>, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbExecutionStrategy, Boolean, Boolean)
0000003baea1cb68 00007ffd8ccdefc7 [StubHelperFrame: 0000003baea1cb68] 
0000003baea1cbd0 00007ffd2dc5503a System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1+c__DisplayClass7[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].b__5()
0000003baea1cc40 00007ffd2dc4727b *** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.Func`1<System.__Canon>)
0000003baea1ccb0 00007ffd2dc55200 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].GetResults(System.Nullable`1<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.MergeOption>)
0000003baea1cd10 00007ffd2dc552bb System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator>b__0()
0000003baea1cd40 00007ffd2dc558e2 System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].MoveNext()
0000003baea1cd90 00007ffd8ba749c8 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
0000003baea1ce00 00007ffd8a151200 Unable to load image C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Core\679e2ddbbd0b9e07c385ab225a90ddf1\System.Core.ni.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Core.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for System.Core.ni.dll
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
0000003baea1ce40 00007ffd2e2d9564 *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for FosService.Web.App.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for FosService.Web.App.dll
FosService.Web.App.dll!Unknown
0000003baea1cf60 00007ffd2e2cb24c FosService.Web.App.dll!Unknown
0000003baea1d1b0 00007ffd2d6e09e6 FosService.Web.App.dll!Unknown
0000003baea1d380 00007ffd2e6c14ce Unable to load image C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.ServiceModel\71ec501fa4f9ad90209b54b488b8835a\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
DynamicClass.SyncInvokeGetDataForDateRange(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])
0000003baea1d3c0 00007ffd87be6352 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[] ByRef)
0000003baea1d5a0 00007ffd87be28d5 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
0000003baea1d950 00007ffd87be20d0 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
0000003baea1da00 00007ffd87be17bb System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
0000003baea1dbe0 00007ffd87be01fe System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean)
0000003baea1dca0 00007ffd87bdf74e System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext, Boolean, System.ServiceModel.OperationContext)
0000003baea1e080 00007ffd87bddb72 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext, System.ServiceModel.OperationContext)
0000003baea1e100 00007ffd87bdd6bb System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(System.IAsyncResult)
0000003baea1e160 00007ffd80f7acc2 Unable to load image C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Servd1dec626#\ac8c62999c92689636bd79c04b3b5a5b\System.ServiceModel.Internals.ni.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.ServiceModel.Internals.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for System.ServiceModel.Internals.ni.dll
System.Runtime.Fx+AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult)
0000003baea1e1b0 00007ffd8884dd15 System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility+c__DisplayClass4.b__2(System.AsyncCallback, System.IAsyncResult)
0000003baea1e210 00007ffd80f757ea System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean)
0000003baea1e2c0 00007ffd80f7aee1 System.Runtime.InputQueue`1+AsyncQueueReader[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].Set(Item<System.__Canon>)
0000003baea1e310 00007ffd80f7a80c System.Runtime.InputQueue`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].EnqueueAndDispatch(Item<System.__Canon>, Boolean)
0000003baea1e480 00007ffd80f7a3de System.Runtime.InputQueue`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].EnqueueAndDispatch(System.__Canon, System.Action, Boolean)
0000003baea1e4f0 00007ffd87c09132 System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].Enqueue(System.__Canon, System.Action, Boolean)
0000003baea1e550 00007ffd87c08ace System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline+EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue(System.IAsyncResult)
0000003baea1e5d0 00007ffd87c0893a System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline+EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.HandleParseIncomingMessage(System.IAsyncResult)
0000003baea1e600 00007ffd8100fe04 System.Runtime.AsyncResult.SyncContinue(System.IAsyncResult)
0000003baea1e650 00007ffd87c078e0 System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline+EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReplyChannelAcceptor, System.Action, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
0000003baea1e6a0 00007ffd87c06fd8 System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1+HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].ProcessHttpContextAsync()
0000003baea1e730 00007ffd87c06dca System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].BeginHttpContextReceived(System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext, System.Action, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
0000003baea1e790 00007ffd8217dc8c Unable to load image C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Serv14b62006#\9a6e8fee6a6af925251e234fc3a9f6c3\System.ServiceModel.Activation.ni.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.ServiceModel.Activation.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for System.ServiceModel.Activation.ni.dll
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult)
0000003baea1e830 00007ffd82177f54 System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
0000003baea1e8b0 00007ffd82177c35 System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
0000003baea1e960 00007ffd82177bc3 System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(System.Object)
0000003baea1e9b0 00007ffd82138a02 System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
0000003baea1ea00 00007ffd82177b43 System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(System.Object)
0000003baea1ea60 00007ffd80f7bf11 System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler+ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
0000003baea1eac0 00007ffd80f7be90 System.Runtime.Fx+IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
0000003baea1eb20 00007ffd8baf5156 System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
0000003baea1ecd8 00007ffd8cc4afb3 [GCFrame: 0000003baea1ecd8] 
0000003baea1eea8 00007ffd8cc4afb3 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 0000003baea1eea8] 
0000003baea1f038 00007ffd8cc4afb3 [ContextTransitionFrame: 0000003baea1f038] 
0000003baea1f258 00007ffd8cc4afb3 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 0000003baea1f258]
```

Here is the code: 
The query below brings in at least 3k accounts into memory. Then it loops through the accounts and makes lazy loading queries to fill account information.
At-least 15 sql queries for 1 account.

The out of memory exception occurs when loading a navigation property via lazy loading.

```
var account  = dbcontext.Account.Where(m => m.startDate >= startDate && m.endDate <= endDate);
```

Comment: The log doesn't provide us anything to help you with. Provide us the related code for `GetDataForDateRange`

Comment: done see original message

Comment: See this SO question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188678/entity-framework-lazy-loading-with-asnotracking