# EF's AsNoTracking() doesn't prevent the resulting entities to be tracked (+ still have lazy loading on them)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have the following code in aync method:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

// ...

protected internal async Task<Customer> GetCustomerAsync(int entityId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    IQueryable<Customer> query = (await this.Repository.GetAll(cancellationToken)).Where(e => e.Id == entityId);

    query = query.Include(e => e.Partners);

    string sql = query.ToString();

    return await query.AsNotTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

The sql variable contains, something like this:

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
[Project1].[EntityId] AS [EntityId], 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[OtherColumn] AS [OtherColumn], 
[Project1].[Name] AS [Name],
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[EntityId] AS [EntityId], 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent2].[OtherColumn] AS [OtherColumn]
    [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent3].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId], 
    [Extent3].[PartnerId] AS [PartnerId], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM   [op].[CustomerAcls] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [op].[Customers] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[EntityId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [op].[CustomerPartners] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent3].[CustomerId]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[AccessRight] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent2].[Id] = @p__linq__2)
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[UserId] ASC, [Project1].[EntityId] ASC, [Project1].[Id] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

**UPDATE -----**

The code of the repository is like the following:

```
public class CustomerRepository<TAcl> : ICustomerRepository
    where TAcl : class, IAcl<Customer>, new()
{
    private readonly DbSet<TAcl> aclSet;

    public CustomerRepository(
        BranchDbContext branchDbContext,
        Func<BranchDbContext, DbSet<TAcl>> aclSetFunc)
    {   
        this.aclSet = aclSetFunc(branchDbContext);
    }

    public async Task<IQueryable<Customer>> GetAll(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        int minAccessRight = //...
        int currentUserId = //...

        return from acl in (from acl in this.aclSet
                       where acl.UserId == currentUserId &&
                             acl.AccessRight >= minAccessRight
                       select acl)
        select acl.Entity;
    }
}
```

**------------**

Despite of the use of the **AsNoTracking()** method (see return statement), and even though that I made sure the repository gives me back a LinqToEntities query (it's not already materialized), the resulting returned instance (of the method **GetCustomerAsync**) has still lazy loading capabilities.

The documentation is so vague, it says:

> If the underlying query object does not have a AsNoTracking method, then calling this method will have no affect.

Does someone see where the problem is in my code or understand what the documentation says?

THX

Comment: Side note: if `GetAll` returns `IQueryable` there's no point in making it `async`. That said, you should still show the method because there's probably some clue in there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: You have AsNotTracking when it should be AsNoTracking.  Are you sure your example code is accurate?

Comment: @GertArnold I agree. However, it is not me who did that, it's legacy code. I have to use it as is.

Comment: @JohnGlenn Sorry, that simply was a typo.

Comment: Can you add the code for the repository method being called?

Comment: @JohnGlenn I added an update to the post with the code you asked. THX

Comment: Seeing data for navigation properties does not mean that the entities you queried are tracked. If the linked entities (the other end of the navigation property) were previously loaded on the same context and are tracked, then they will be populated on your untracked entity.

Comment: The idea that untracked entities shouldn't lazy load isn't true. They do, and why not? If you don't want them to lazy load, you have to turn off lazy loading on the context level.

Comment: @GertArnold thank you. But how can I do if I only want this instance to NOT have lazy loading on it? As told before, it's  legacy code and I cannot modify it.

Comment: @JohnGlenn No, if entities are not tracked, EF will not apply relationship fixup. That only works on tracked entities.

Comment: @GertArnold I fixed my comment: But how can I do if I only want this instance to NOT have lazy loading on it

Comment: Then you need a way to tell your repository to stop returning lazy-loading proxies (`context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`) or to suspend lazy loading (`Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`), which means: you need access to the legacy code. Or you shouldn't query entities but project the query immediately to DTO or view model classes.

Comment: @GertArnold I was sure it was not possible to have lazy loading on untracked entities because of that test example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6iyahU

Comment: That fiddle is meaningless because everything happens in the same context.

Comment: @GertArnold I could have sworn that EF will saturate the navigation property on the untracked entity with an already tracked entity. I must have an include in the untracked query that I'm not remembering... I'll double check later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not necessarily indicative that the entities are tracked as a result of that query. EF 6 will also still lazy load referenced entities in non-tracked results provided lazy loading is enabled and the navigation properties are `virtual`.

As a simple example with a Parent and Children collection:

EF 6:

```
using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
    var parent = context.Parents.AsNoTracking().Single(x => x.ParentId == 1);
    var count = parent.Children.Count;
}
```

Here with lazy loading enabled and the Children declared as a `virtual ICollection<Child>`, EF 6 will trigger a lazy load call when parent.Children is accessed. This can be verified by running a profiler against your DB with a breakpoint and you will see the lazy load call go out.

To avoid this you would need to turn Lazy Loading off, or ensure the Children property is not declared as `virtual`. In either of those cases, "count" would come back as 0 (or trigger a null ref if not initialized to an empty list)

With EF core things are a bit different. By default with EF Core, Lazy Loading is disabled so "count" would always come back as 0. If you enable lazy loading proxies in your DbContext then the above code would result in an InvalidOperationException as now an `AsNoTracking()` entity is properly detected as Detached and throws this exception if you attempt to lazy load from a detached instance. (EF6 allowed this if the DbContext was still in scope)

Both EF6 and EF Core will not pre-populate related entities that might already be tracked when fetching a `NoTracking()` instance.

For example, provided lazy loading is disabled or non-virtual collection:

```
using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
    var parent = context.Parents.Include(x => x.Children).AsNoTracking().Single(x => x.ParentId == 1);
    var count = parent.Children.Count;  // eager load, will return count.
}

using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
    var parent = context.Parents.AsNoTracking().Single(x => x.ParentId == 1);
    var count = parent.Children.Count;  // 0.
}

using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
    var children = context.Children.Where(x => x.ParentId == 1).ToList();
    var parent = context.Parents.Single(x => x.ParentId == 1);
    var count = parent.Children.Count;  // not eager or lazy loaded, will still return count. 
     // (This can be inaccurate if only *some* children were previously loaded.)
}

using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
    var children = context.Children.Where(x => x.ParentId == 1).ToList();
    var parent = context.Parents.AsNoTracking().Single(x => x.ParentId == 1);
    var count = parent.Children.Count;  // will still return 0.
}
```

So if you are seeing something else unexpectedly and lazy loading is definitely disabled and confirmed not to be happening (no queries observed in a profiler) then I suspect you have something else at play.

This code for instance sends off red flags:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<Customer>> GetAll(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    int minAccessRight = //...
    int currentUserId = //...

    return from acl in (from acl in this.aclSet
                   where acl.UserId == currentUserId &&
                         acl.AccessRight >= minAccessRight
                   select acl)
    select acl.Entity;
}
```

`IQueryable` returning methods do not need to be declared as `async` and possibly should not as this may be triggering a tracking-like query actually executing or some other odd behaviour.  Instead, try:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> GetAll(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    int minAccessRight = //...
    int currentUserId = //...

    var query = (from acl in this.aclSet
                   where acl.UserId == currentUserId &&
                         acl.AccessRight >= minAccessRight
                   select acl);
    return query;
}
```

Then in calling:

```
IQueryable<Customer> query = Repository.GetAll(cancellationToken)
    .Include(e => e.Partners)
    .Where(e => e.Id == entityId)
    .AsNoTracking();

return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

The execution of the query is still asynchronous, and that is where the `async` matters. The only reason the query composition might need to be asynchronous is if in building that query resulted in some particularly expensive checks etc. that might benefit from being `async`, however I'd probably delegate that back out and have those values pre-fetched asynchronously and have the values passed in as parameters. (I.e. if getting minAccessRight/currentUserId etc. handed off to async calls, load these IDs and pass them in as parameters instead)

Answer (score 0):

How did you check that the entity is not tracked. The `AsNoTracking` method's purpose is to exclude the fetched records from entity framework change tracker (for example when you are using the data only for read purposes and want to prevent accidentally persisting data in database).

See `AsNoTracking` documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

I suggest to check DbContext (after you run the query) and check whether the entity you fetched from database is being tracked in change tracker.

Also consider using `FindAsync` instead of `FirstOrDefaultAsync` in case that the `entityId` is primary key of the `Customer` table.

This is how I would approach writing the method:

```
protected internal async Task<Customer> GetCustomerAsync(int entityId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return this.Repository
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Include(e => e.Partners)
        .FindAsync(entityId, cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: The resulting entities ARE tracked, and this is the problem. I know this because when I use the navigation properties I get the children entities, even though I didn't include them (with the IQueryable<>.Include(...) method)